# Dynamic menus based on roles using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could i get menus to be viewed based on the role?
This code works properly, but I found an issue `$role_id` is only set after refreshing the code. It cannot be assigned without reload.

```
angular.module('main', [])
            .config(routeConfig);

            function routeConfig($stateProvider,$rootScope)
            {
               angular.injector(['ngCookies'])
                   .invoke(['$cookies','$cookieStore', function($cookies,$cookieStore)
                 {
                     $role_id = $cookieStore.get('rolecookies');
                     console.log($role_id);
                     if($rootScope.role_id==1)
                     {
                          $stateProvider
                         .state('main.admin', 
                         {
                           url: '/admin',
                           controller: 'psCtrl',
                           templateUrl: 'app/pages/admin/main/main.view.html',
                           title: 'Admin',
                           sidebarMeta: {
                               icon: 'ion-android-home',
                               order: 1,
                              },
                          })
                         .state('main',
                         {
                             url: '/main',
                             template : '<ui-view></ui-view>',
                             abstract: true,
                             title: 'Main Home',
                             sidebarMeta: {
                             icon: 'ion-android-home',
                             order: 1,
                              },
                          });
                      }
            }]);
    }
```

Comment: i need to get role_id without refreshing

Comment: share me where actually ur setting the rolecookies...

Comment: first check condition for cookies available or not  if($cookieStore.get('rolecookies') == undefined) {  } else { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your cookie has been set,try

```
<!-- -->
<body ng-init="getCookie()">

$scope.getCookie = function(){
       $role_id = $cookieStore.get('rolecookies');
       //I'm not familiar with NgCookies but this is what I mostly workaround with it when avoiding refresh

}
```

Comment: Thank You. I have solved the issue by using the menu items into the cookies which will automatically shown in the UI by Scope variables.